# What's the best way to level your specialization HQ?

Tags: simcity-2013

It's kind of hard to level your HQ, especially when you're starting out on a brand new city without another city to help develop. What's the way to get those xxx profit/day requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to level xx profit/day HQs specifically is the following method.

1. Calculate amount of goods you need to sell.
2. Calculate and build enough trade depots to hold that amount.
3. Set the trade depots so they do not export goods.
4. Let your producing buildings fill up all of your trade depots completely.
5. At 12:00AM pause the game and set all of your trade depots to export.
6. Through the progression of the day, all of the goods in the depots should be sold, giving you enough profit to level up your HQ.

Comment: This is by far the best way to do it but can feel a little cheaty i suppose :)

Comment: @teeone its genius economics, disney does it with their classic movies, except they wait 10-20 years to periodically release their movies.